# MySQL split values to multiple rows two table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have table :
**table a:**

```
id | content    
1  | a, b, c    
2  | b
3  | b, c, d
```

**Table b:**

```
id | name  | value  
1  | a     | 3000
2  | b     | 4505
3  | c     | 1257
4  | k     | 2323
```

**i want output like this :**

```
id | value             | content 
1  | 3000, 4505, 1257  | a, b, c
2  | 4505              | b
3  | 1257              | c
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try joining the two tables with the help of `FIND_IN_SET`.  Then aggregate by the b `id` to generate the CSV values:

```sql
SELECT
    a.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.value ORDER BY b.id) value,
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY b.id) content
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(b.name, a.content) > 0
GROUP BY
    a.id;
```

Note: You should generally avoid storing CSV data in your SQL tables.  Having the need to use `FIND_IN_SET` is usually a data smell.